# Using Automapper to populate a list in an entity class from a DTO property

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm very new to using AutoMapper and I've spent a few days googling for a solution with no luck. I am trying to map a DTO, shown below, to my entity class, which contains multiple levels of information (Year,Quarter,Season,Period,Week,Day).

Here's my DTO:

```
public class CalendarDto
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Quarter { get; set; }
    public string Season { get; set; }
    public int DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int WeekOfYear { get; set; }
    public int DayOfYear { get; set; }
    public int WeekOfPeriod { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the first two levels of my entity:

```
    public class Calendar : ICalendar<string>
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public CalendarQuarter Quarters { get; set; }
    }

   public class CalendarQuarter
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Quarter { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public List<CalendarSeason> Seasons { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, I have additional levels of nesting from year to quarter, to season, to period, to week and to day. I just provide the first level, year to quarter, because I'm sure once I figure out that one the rest will be straight forward.

I tried with the profile being set to map each class separately, as shown below, from the DTO because all property values match.

```
public class CalendarProfile : Profile
{
    public CalendarProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CalendarDto, Calendar>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CalendarDto, CalendarQuarter>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CalendarDto, CalendarSeason>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CalendarDto, CalendarPeriod>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CalendarDto, CalendarWeek>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CalendarDto, CalendarDay>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

When I attempt to map the DTO to the entity in the handler, only the Calendar class is mapped and the CalendarQuarters list is null. It was my understanding that a profile is the same as a config and that all the mapping created in the profile would be executed when Map is executed. Obviously, I'm either wrong, have my mapping set up incorrectly, or both! Lol

```
var calendar = _mapper.Map<CalendarDto, Calendar>(parms.Dto);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Never use automaper in such way. An author of automaper said that automaper is designed to map from entity to DTO or VM. Never from DTO to entity. You should use constructor or any design pattern e.g. factory. Using automaper in such way will make you many problems when project grow up.

Answer (score -1):

First it is important to mention that using automapper can make mapping look easier, but it is impossible to debug code and you can have problems when your project becomes big and mapping is not thing that is so complicated (you can always map explicitly and debug easily) it is just boring so it is good to have that in mind before you decide to use it, read this articles:
[article1](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/), [article2](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/).

You should read [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html) if using automapper. I think that you need something like this:

```cs
CreateMap<Calendar, CalendarDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.Quarters.Quarter, 
                                             opt => opt.Quarter)
                                  .ForMember(dest => dest.Quarters.Quarter.Seasons.Season
                                             opt => opt.Season);
```

I removed reverse map because I copied this from my project and changed properties, I hope that you can apply to all properties. Of course you have many properties so you can chain `ForMember` and define all mappings, if you don't do this mapper is mapping only properties with same name.

Comment: Never use automaper is such way in big commercial projects. It will be unmaintainable, especially when DTO will not be simply the same structure as entity.

Comment: Ok I saw comment, but can you elaborate? I used on college with colleagues and we finished project with success and we had many entities, and many DTOs. Difference here is that in this case there are many levels of entity, but I don't see that as big problem.

Comment: Because your project lasted 1 year. I wish you never trying to debug 10 years automaper based application ;). https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/ there are many articles. https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/

Comment: So problem is in practice it becomes very ugly and is not maintainable? Also what will be appropriate to do with answer?

Comment: It is better to create some kind of factory method or factory class. You can then call var product = _factory.CreateProduct(productsDto); automaper is very fast in development but very bad in maintenance. It is hard to write unit tests. It is very bad when your business logic is coded in automaper configuration instead of business services.

Comment: @zolty13 Thank you for mentioning, this is also conclusion in article you provided link. I will edit my answer.